# Auto mapper - Edit object before map

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have skill object which `EmployeeSkillDTO` type ,I want to use auto mapper but i want to set `CreationTime = DateTime.Now` but notice that skill object have `creationTime = null`

EmployeeSkillController:

```
EmployeeSkill ski = context.EmployeeSkill.Where(r => r.SkillID == skill.SkillID && r.EmployeeID == skill.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

if (ski == null){
   Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>{
      cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeSkillDTO, EmployeeSkill>();
   });

   var map = Mapper.Map<EmployeeSkillDTO, EmployeeSkill>(skill);

   //ski = new EmployeeSkill
   //{
   //    SkillID = skill.SkillID,
   //    EmployeeID = skill.EmployeeID,
   //    Major = skill.Major,
   //    YearOfExperience = skill.YearOfExperience,
   //    CreatedBY = skill.CreatedBY,
   //    CreationTime = DateTime.Now,
   //};
context.EmployeeSkill.Add(map);
```

The commented part before using auto mapper .....

Comment: Note that mappings are typically defined at startup of your program, not after execution of a query. I'm not sure if there is a technical need or benefit to do so, but I can imagine that it is more efficient to define it only once.

Comment: you mean create mapper class in project and call it in global.asax ?

Comment: I have not used that setup personally but I think it would be OK. Search `automapper createmap global.asax` for examples, you'll find plenty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeSkillDTO, EmployeeSkill>()
   .ForMember(x => x.CreationTime, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => DateTime.Now));
```

might work?